# Can I avoid the typecasting of interface method parameters to concrete types for same family of classes?

Tags: java, c#, interface, polymorphism, refactoring

I have 3 interfaces roughly as follows : 
`IData` which wraps around required data `IDataInfo` to provide meta-data about the `IData` and

```
IDataProvider
{
   IData GetData(IDataInfo iDataInfo);
}
```

I have several family of derived interfaces for the above interfaces. For Eg :

1. `IBikeData : IData` , `IBikeDataInfo : IDataInfo` and `IBikeDataProvider : IDataProvider`
2. `ICarData : IData` , `ICarDataInfo : IDataInfo` and `ICarDataProvider : IDataProvider` and so on.

Now, in the concrete implementations of `IData GetData(IDataInfo iDataInfo)` for `IBikeDataProvider` and `ICarDataProvider` I need to typecast the incoming `iDataInfo` parameter to respective derived types (`IBikeDataInfo` and `ICarDataInfo`) for other to access other specific functionalities. I am slightly uncomfortable with this typecasting in each concrete implementation, which I think is not right thing to do. Is there a way I can refactor my design to prevent this ?

Comment: Concrete classes shouldn't begin with an `I` - that normally indicates an interface.

Comment: If your implementation requires a specific type, then it should not be defined to take an interface. It may also be more helpful to provide sample code for the interfaces and classes you're referring to, especially one which shows the casting operation you want to avoid.

Comment: I am sorry to have mentioned them as concrete types. They are basically derived interfaces which would be concreted by respective classes.

Comment: I want interfaces here because there is another module like scheduler where I would need to handle several derived family of interfaces in the same way without any knowledge of the actual types.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like generics would be the answer here, assuming you can adjust your `IDataProvider` interface. If you make a contravariant and covariant type parameter to coincide with your `IData` and `IDataInfo` types, you can switch the definition up to get something like this:

```
public interface IDataProvider<in TIn, out TOut> where TIn : IDataInfo 
                                                 where TOut : IData 
{
    TOut GetData(TIn dataInfo);
}
```

Your `IBikeDataProvider` interface could then be declared as the following:

```
public interface IBikeDataProvider : IDataProvider<IBikeDataInfo, IBikeData> { }
```

Which would lead to the following concrete class instance:

```
public class BikeDataProvider : IBikeDataProvider
{
    public IBikeData GetData(IBikeDataInfo dataInfo)
    {
        // Do things
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to handle all the families in a similar way using the base interfaces in a module like say scheduler. If that is the case, would the above solution be feasible ? Since, I would need the types for instantiating and working with derived family of interfaces and classes.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar No, you won't be able to do that. This is the type-safe option I can think of, but to be type safe you'll have to supply some types at compile time _as far as I know_.